# Using ng-repeat to repeat Google Chart charts

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-visualization

I'm still in the process of learning AngularJS, so forgive me if I say anything stupid. I'm using Google Chart for creating my charts.

Each time the user click on a button, my webpage display one more chart. So I thought about using ng-repeat to display them. Also, each chart can be closed (and not displayed anymore) with a button (the img in the following code) :

```
<div class="chartContainer" ng-repeat="x in arrayDiv">
    <img src="close.png"/>
</div>
```

To create a chart I proceed like this :

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': chartType, 
    'containerId': //???
});
```

So my question is : **how do I extend $scope.arrayDiv each time a chart is created ? And how do I get the id of the div created this way to affect the chart to it ?**

Comment: See - https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart

Comment: I wasn't aware this existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with angular-google-chart,

Refer :`https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/bar/`

```
<div class="chartContainer" ng-repeat="data in arrayDiv">
    <div layout-padding layout-margin  google-chart chart="drawChart(x)">        
    </div> 
</div>

$scope.drawChart = function (value) {

    $scope.chartData = [];
    var chartValue = {
        c: [{
           v: 'subject
        }, {
            v: 5,
            f: " questions"
        }, {
            v: 6,
            f:  " questions"
        }]

    };
    $scope.chartData.push(chartValue);
    $scope.qaChart = {};
    $scope.qaChart.type = "BarChart";
    $scope.qaChart.data = {
        "cols": [{
            id: "Sections",
            label: "Subject",
            type: "string"
        }, {
            id: "Correct",
            label: "Correct",
            type: "number"
        }, {
            id: "Wrong",
            label: "Wrong",
            type: "number"
        }],
        "rows": $scope.chartData
    };
    $scope.qaChart.options = {

        "isStacked": "true",
        "fill": 20,
        "displayExactValues": true,
        "colors": ['#4CAF50', '#EF5350', '#00adee'],
        "vAxis": {
            "title": " Questions",                
        },
        "hAxis": {
            "title": "Details",
        }
    };
    return $scope.qaChart;
};
```